# How to rename part of the volume label in a batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am creating a batch file to change some things on a Windows XP embedded machine (copy files, change registry settings). One of the things is to change the volume label from

> "AAA BBBB vX.X"

to

> "CCC DDD vX.X"

where 'vX.X' is a version number that has to stay the same (e.g. v1.23).

How can I do it in a batch file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your volume name has always exactly this shape (SOMETHING SOMETHING SOMETHING) you can try this:

```
@ECHO OFF
FOR /F "tokens=8 delims= " %%G IN ('vol') DO SET lastToken=%%G
LABEL C: CCC DDD %lastToken%
```

`tokens=8` will give you the third token of the volume name (split by whitespace) - in your case vX.X.

`tokens=6` would be AAA and `tokens=7` BBBB.

Obvoiusly this code only works in you are on drive `C:` and you want to rename drive `C:`. If you want to rename `D:` just add `D:` as new line just below `@ECHO OFF` and change `C:` to `D:` in the last line and so on.

Comment: Seems relatively  simple, but I would never make up this my self. Thanks, after the weekend I will let you know if it works.